# Merge columns in data.frame after removal of duplicate strings

Tags: r, string, dataframe, data.table, strsplit

I have a data.frame`data` of character vectors as follows.

```
x <- c("kal, Kon, Jor, Kara", "Bruce, Helena, Martha, Terry", "connor, oliver, Roy",  
       "Alan, Guy, Simon, Kyle")
y <- c("Mon, Cir, John, Jor", "Damian, Terry, Jason", "Mia, Roy", "John, Cary")
data <- data.frame(x,y, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I am trying to concatenate strings in the two columns `x` and `y` to a new column `z`. I want to remove the duplicates and sort the words separated by `,` before concatenating the strings in a row. I am able to achieve this as follows.

```
x <- strsplit(data$x, split=", ")
y <- strsplit(data$y, split=", ")
data$z <- sapply(1:length(x), function(i) paste(sort(union(x[[i]], y[[i]])), 
                                                collapse=", "))
```

Is there a faster way to do this without creating the intermediate lists, maybe using `data.table`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To go further with the idea you had, you can do, without creating intermediate lists :

```
data$z<-apply(data,1,function(vec){
                        paste(unique(strsplit(paste(vec[1],vec[2],sep=", "),", ")[[1]]),collapse=", ")
                      })

> data
                             x                    y                                           z
1          kal, Kon, Jor, Kara  Mon, Cir, John, Jor         kal, Kon, Jor, Kara, Mon, Cir, John
2 Bruce, Helena, Martha, Terry Damian, Terry, Jason Bruce, Helena, Martha, Terry, Damian, Jason
3          connor, oliver, Roy             Mia, Roy                    connor, oliver, Roy, Mia
4       Alan, Guy, Simon, Kyle           John, Cary          Alan, Guy, Simon, Kyle, John, Cary
```

although slower, base R is not that bad, based on the 3e4-row dataset of @akrun :

```
>  microbenchmark(cath(), akrun2(), unit='relative', times=100L)
Unit: relative
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
   cath() 1.429732 1.425991 1.427143 1.427015 1.435986 1.360235   100   b
 akrun2() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100  a
```

Comment: Did you really run your benchmarks on a 4-row dataset?

Comment: @AnandaMahto It might be better to compare on a 1e6 dataset.

Comment: @CathG Please note that in your code, there is no `sort`, which I think might be one factor that changes the timings.

Comment: @CathG You mentioned about running 1e6 dataset, do you have the timings?

Comment: @akrun, it never ended so I stopped it because it was slowing all other "jobs" and I saw you already displayed results for a pretty big dataset...

Comment: @CathG It is not very big dataset, as I don't have time to run these things.

Answer (score 5):

You could try a `regex` solution.  But, this won't sort as you may wanted.

```
v1 <- paste(data[,1], data[,2], sep=", ")
data$z <- sub('(\\b\\S+\\b)(?=.*\\b\\1\\b.*),', "", v1, perl=TRUE)
```

The regex can be viewed at [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/sP5uY7/1)

Other options include

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(data.table)
cbind(data[,1:2],cSplit(setDT(data)[, indx:=1:.N],
      c('x', 'y'), sep=",", 'long')[ ,
     list(z=toString(unique(na.omit(unlist(.SD))))),
                           by=indx][,indx:=NULL])

                                 x                    y
 #1:          kal, Kon, Jor, Kara  Mon, Cir, John, Jor
 #2: Bruce, Helena, Martha, Terry Damian, Terry, Jason
 #3:          connor, oliver, Roy             Mia, Roy
 #4:       Alan, Guy, Simon, Kyle           John, Cary
  #                                       z
 #1:         kal, Kon, Jor, Kara, Mon, Cir, John
 #2: Bruce, Helena, Martha, Terry, Damian, Jason
 #3:                    connor, oliver, Roy, Mia
 #4:          Alan, Guy, Simon, Kyle, John, Cary
```

Or using `stringi` package

```
 library(stringi)
 data$z <- vapply(stri_extract_all_regex(paste(data$x, data$y), '\\w+'),
                function(x) toString(sort(unique(x))), character(1))
```

#### Benchmarks

Based on on a not so big dataset,

```
 data <- data[rep(1:nrow(data), 3e4),]
 row.names(data) <- NULL

 cath <- function(){
       apply(data,1,function(vec){
                    paste(sort(unique(strsplit(paste(vec[1],
                   vec[2],sep=", "),", ")[[1]])),collapse=", ")
                  })
       }

 akrun2 <- function(){
         vapply(stri_extract_all_regex(paste(data$x, data$y), '\\w+'),
                    function(x) toString(sort(unique(x))), character(1))
      }

 akrun3 <- function(){
    v1 <- paste(data[,1], data[,2], sep=", ")
    sub('(\\b\\S+\\b)(?=.*\\b\\1\\b.*),', "", v1, perl=TRUE) 
   }

 microbenchmark(cath(), akrun2(), akrun3(),unit='relative', times=10L)
 #Unit: relative
 #   expr       min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 # cath() 11.700071 11.979908 11.700118 11.76762 11.57583 11.40806    10   c
 #akrun2()  7.175622  7.225212  7.217322  7.19431  7.09539  7.31929    10  b 
 #akrun3()  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000    10  a
```

Comment: @CathG Thanks, I considered posting as a new solution.  But, then I thought that it will give a bad precedence for others to post multiple solutions as different posts and also will be a bit unfair as I might get double votes.

Comment: you've got a point, besides, your solution really looks nice with the new edit :-)